Dockerfile on run sh:next not found
I try to build docker with optimization, but when I try to to run it, it says
sh: next:not found
Here is dockerfile
FROM node:20-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /src

## Set local timezone in alpine linux
ARG TZ="Europe/Bratislava"
ENV TZ=${TZ}
RUN apk upgrade -qU \
&& apk add -qu tzdata \
&& ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TZ} /etc/localtime \
&& echo ${TZ} > /etc/timezone \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:20-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /src
COPY --from=builder /src/package.json .
COPY --from=builder /src/package-lock.json .
COPY --from=builder /src/next.config.js .
COPY --from=builder /src/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /src/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder /src/.next/static ./.next/static


EXPOSE 3000

CMD npx next start

This build got around 160MB and I want to avoid to COPY node_modules to runner because then it got almost 1GB size.

The binary is probably in node_modules/.bin.  You do need to COPY the node_modules tree into your final image or otherwise install the packages from your package.json.  If you're not copying your library tree into the final image, it won't be there, and you can't use any of the commands or libraries your application needs.

@DavidMaze so there is no better way to make optimazation without node_modules in runner ? I just try to reduce my build because that build got almost 1GB and I tihink it's big for smaller project there is reason why I try to find better solution for dockerization.

The node_modules tree is required – it contains your application's library dependencies.  I might put Docker aside for a moment, run something like du node_modules in a host-based Node setup, and try to figure out which libraries need so much space.

Try to use CMD ["node", "server.js"] instead of CMD npx next start on the last line.
